# Statistics and matrix algebra in Ruby

Tags: ruby, matrix, statistics, algebra, matrix-inverse

I need to inverse a variance-covariance matrix in Ruby and vector by matrix multiplication. Which numerical Ruby library/Gem should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the 'matrix' library:

```
http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/index.html
```

Answer (score 3):

A numerically more stable possibility than direct inversion is to use a [Cholesky decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) with the package you find [here](http://www.approximity.com/public/download/code.html):

```
require 'Cholesky.rb'
require 'pp'
# m is the covariance matrix you want to invert (it is positive semidefinite)
l = m.cholesky
li = l.inverse
lit = li.transpose
# lit*li is approximately the inverse and the next line shows this
pp lit*li*m
```

Better than inverting l is to use the method described in the wikpedia article linked above.

If your problem is numerically too unstable then consider the [Singular Value Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), but I don't have code for it.

Answer (score 3):

If you can compile code, use ruby-gsl

`gem install gsl`

The inverse can be obtained using LU module

`inverse=GSL::Linalg::LU.invert(matrix)`

Answer (score 0):

There is [NMatrix](https://github.com/sciruby/nmatrix). There is support for various operations, including some from BLAS and LAPACK (by using ATLAS).